# jsonwebtoken doesn't expire

Tags: node.js, passport.js, jwt, json-web-token

I'm using jsonwebtoken package for node.js:

Creating the token like that:

```
var token = jwt.sign(user, tokenSecret, {expiresInMinutes: 1});
```

Verifying like that:

```
jwt.verify(token, tokenSecret, function(err, decoded) {
    if(err) return done(new Error('Invalid authentication!'));
    if(!decoded) return done(null, false);

    return done(null, decoded, { scope: 'all'});
});
```

However my token never expires (I waited some minutes between the "requests").

Comment: Hi, can you show some token example, pls

Comment: Interestingly, the body does not have a iat field. And carefully,  token contain password hash

Comment: How do you know what's inside my token? Don't you need my secret key to decrypt?

Comment: No i dont need, this is the essence JWT=)

Comment: if this real roken i recommend remove him

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i have some idea, try dump user object before create token. Something like this:

```
db.user.find(query, function(user){
    var userInfo = {
        id: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        role: user.role
    }

    return jwt.sign(userInfo, tokenSecret, {expiresInMinutes: 1});
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did the trick. And of course I have modified the "format" of my token, containing only not security-/privacy relevant information.

Comment: Oh my..... i've been digging into the source for hours with node-debug to understand why it didnt work. Answers like this are the reason why im still coding today ,thank you bro